# Reading a CSV file in C# correctly for a print preview

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, reader

First of all, I'm using a csv file to store data from a DataGridView into it. Now I'm trying to show a printPreview with the data in the csv file. I'm using this:

```
    public void ReadDocument()
    {
        string docName = @"printDataGridView.csv";
        string docPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        form1.printDocument1.DocumentName = docName;

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(docPath + @"\" + docName, FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            form1.documentContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        form1.stringToPrint = form1.documentContents;
    }
```

My problem is that I'm getting a print preview where the values are just listed seperated by semicolons. Want I need is to show the data like it is displayed in the CSV file - tabularly and "clean". So one column with the header and it's values right under it, then the second column and so on...
Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Did you try opening the csv file in an editor ? The semicolon separated values _is_ the underlying format of the file. When you treat the data as a string, that is what you will get. You will need to parse the data into a data structure, and put it in some kind of grid control to achieve what you want.

Comment: By "semicolons" do you mean commas?  Also, if the CSV file looked tabular and "clean," you probably weren't looking at it the actual file contents (as in a text editor) but a spreadsheet-like representation of it (as in Excel).

Comment: Don' use CSV.  Best to use a DataTable as datasource to your DataGrid
View.  Then you can Read/Write DataTable to file using ReadXml() or WriteXml().  Else use tab delimited instead of CSV.

Comment: How can I read the values of a Data Table into a string format with the print preview? I mean, can I pass it into a string or something else?

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I will try this with the XML reader/writer. What do you mean with tab delimited?

Comment: How can I read the xml file and display it in a printpreview?